# Helm install Kong creating postgresql container and services in DB less mode

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kong, kong-ingress

Helm is creating postgresql-0 container, postgresql and postgresql-headless services even in DB less mode. Below is my command.

helm install stable/kong --set ingressController.enabled=true --set postgresql.enabled=false --set env.database=off

When I use Yaml file it is not creating these components but with helm it is. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can update on values.yaml with ingressController.enabled=true  postgresql.enabled=false env.database=off and try.